# Segmented control and table view issue swift

Tags: swift

so I am creating a table view with segmented control. at first - I didn't do segmented control but modified some code to at it. When I add numbers to my array, it is not actually populating the cells of the table view. In the table view every time I click a button that appends an amount to the array, the lines increase, but no data is shown. So I know it is working, but it is just not actually displaying the numbers in the table view cells. is there a specific reason why my code will not populate the views?

```
class SpendingHistoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


var savedInformation = false
var newDefault : Double?
var selectedSegment = 1
let array2 = ["1","2","3"]


let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewSpending: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var youSpentLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var youSavedLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableViewSpending.delegate = self
    self.tableViewSpending.dataSource = self

    //GETS user defaults that was set in ADDSUBTRACTMONEY VC - and then sets the default to Array- then gets total
    let moneySpentArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "moneySpent") as? [Double] ?? [Double]()
    AddSubtractMoneyController.moneySpentArray = moneySpentArray
    let arraySum = moneySpentArray.reduce(0.0, +)
    youSpentLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", arraySum)

    }

@IBAction func spentSavedAction(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {

    if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        selectedSegment = 1

    }
    else {
        selectedSegment = 2
    }

    self.tableViewSpending.reloadData()
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if selectedSegment == 1 {

    return(AddSubtractMoneyController.moneySpentArray.count)

    }

    else {

        return array2.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    //let cell2 = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell2")

    let cell2 = tableViewSpending.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2")! as UITableViewCell
    let cell = tableViewSpending.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell


    cell.textLabel?.text = String(format: "%.2f", AddSubtractMoneyController.moneySpentArray[indexPath.row])
    cell2.textLabel?.text = array2[indexPath.row]

    self.tableViewSpending.reloadData()

    if selectedSegment == 1 {
        return cell
    }
    else {
        return cell2
    }

        }



}
```

Comment: Where do you append to the array?

Comment: my apologies on the late response. I append the array in another class- where the user enters how much they spent and then clicks save.     @IBAction func submitNewInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        AddSubtractMoneyController.addToMoneySpentArray(amountISpent: Double(outputLabel.text!)!)

        sendBackUpdatedNumber()
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }